# Getting a glibc error when adding using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, glibc, realloc

I have been getting the following error when I compile my program in terminal:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x089660a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ebc2)[0xb7621bc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6f862)[0xb7622862]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb762594d]
./a.out[0x8048668] ./a.out[0x8048fa3]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75cc113]
./a.out[0x80484c1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1835029    /home/fasih/poly/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:06 1835029    /home/fasih/poly/a.out
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 1835029    /home/fasih/poly/a.out
08966000-08987000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b757f000-b759b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4195258    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b759b000-b759c000 r--p 0001b000 08:06 4195258    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b759c000-b759d000 rw-p 0001c000 08:06 4195258    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75b1000-b75b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75b3000-b7729000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4195237    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b7729000-b772b000 r--p 00176000 08:06 4195237    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b772b000-b772c000 rw-p 00178000 08:06 4195237    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
b772c000-b772f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b772f000-b7757000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4195267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b7757000-b7758000 r--p 00028000 08:06 4195267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b7758000-b7759000 rw-p 00029000 08:06 4195267    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
b776c000-b776f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b776f000-b7770000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0         [vdso]
b7770000-b778e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4195224   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b778e000-b778f000 r--p 0001d000 08:06 4195224    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
b778f000-b7790000 rw-p 0001e000 08:06 4195224    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
bfed6000-bfef7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack] Aborted
```

This is my code, it appears to be happening in the polyAdd function, but I also get an assertion fail in multiply so it could be both?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include "poly.h"

    int polyDegree(struct poly *p)
    {
        return p->length-1;
    }
    struct poly *polyCreate()
    {
        struct poly *p = (struct poly *)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
        p->coeff=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        p->size=1;
        p->length=0;
        return p;

    }
    struct poly *polySetCoefficient (struct poly *p, int i, double value)
    {
        if(p == NULL)
            return;

        if(i>=p->size)
        {
            do
            {
                p->size = p->size*2;
            }while(i>=p->size);

            p->coeff = (double *)realloc(p->coeff, p->size*sizeof(double));
        }

        while(i >= p->length)
        {
            p->coeff[p->length] = 0;
            p->length++;
        }

        p->coeff[i] = value;

        return p;
    }
    struct poly *polyDelete(struct poly *p)
    {
        if (p){
        free(p);}

        return 0;
    }
    struct poly *polyCopy(struct poly *p)
    {
        struct poly *nP = polyCreate();
        nP->size =p->size;
        nP->length = p->length;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<(nP->size);i++)
        {
            nP->coeff[i] = p->coeff[i];
        }
        return nP;
    }
    struct poly *polyAdd(struct poly *p0, struct poly *p1)
{
   int i;
   struct poly *pF = polyCreate();
   if (p0->length > p1->length)
   {
        pF = polyCopy(p0);

        for (i=0;i<p1->length;i++)
            pF->coeff[i] += p1->coeff[i];
   }
   else if (p1->length >= p0->length)
   {
        pF = polyCopy(p1);

        for (i=0;i<p0->length;i++)
            pF->coeff[i] += p0->coeff[i];
   }
   return pF;

}
    struct poly *polyPrime (struct poly *p)
    {
        struct poly *pF = polyCreate();
        pF->size = p->size;
        int i,j,k;
        int n = p->size;
        double a[n-1];
        for (i = 1; i <=n;i++)
        {
            a[i-1] = i * p->coeff[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            pF->coeff[i] = a[i];
        }
        return pF;
    }

    struct poly *polyMultiply (struct poly *p0, struct poly *p1)
    {
        struct poly *product = polyCreate();
        product->length = p0->length + p1->length - 1;
        product->size = p0->size + p1->size;
        product->coeff = (double *)malloc(product->size*sizeof(double));

        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<product->length;i++)
            product->coeff[i] = 0;

        for(i=0;i<p0->length;i++)
            for(j=0;j<p1->length;j++)
                product->coeff[i+j] += p0->coeff[i] * p1->coeff[j];

        return product;
    }


    double polyGetCoefficient(struct poly *p, int i)
    {
        double val =p->coeff[i];
        return val;
    }
    int checkZero (double a[], int n)
    {
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
    if (a[x] != 0)
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }

    double polyEval(struct poly *p, double x)
    {
        int i,n;
        double eval=0;
        if (!p)
            return 0;
        if (p)
        n = p->length;
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        for (i = 0; i<=n;i++)
        {
            if (p->coeff[i] == 0)continue;
            if (i == 0)eval += p->coeff[0];
            else
                eval += p->coeff[i]* pow (x,i);
        }
        return eval;
    }

    void polyPrint (struct poly *p)
    {
        int x=0,y,z;
        int n;
        n = p->size;
        double a[p->size];
        for (x = p->size; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            a[x] = p->coeff[x];
        }

        bool check,neg,zero = true;
        if (!checkZero (a,n))
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
        else{
        for(x=(n-1);x>=0;x--)
        {
            check = false;
            neg = false;
            if (x < (n-1) && a[x+1] == 0 && a[x] != 0 && a[x] > 0 && !zero)
                printf(" + ");
            else if (x < (n-1) && a[x+1] == 0 && a[x] != 0 && a[x] < 0 && !zero)
                {
                    printf (" - ");
                    a[x] = a[x] * -1.00;
                }
            if (a[x] == 0)
                continue;
            if (a[x] != 0.0&& x > 1)
            {
                if (a[x] == -1)printf("-x^%d",x);
                else if (a[x] == 1)printf ("x^%d",x);
                else
                printf("%gx^%d",a[x],x);
                check = true;zero = false;
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                if (a[x] == 1)printf("x");
                else
                printf("%gx",a[x]);
                check = true; zero = false;
            }
            else if (x == 0)
            {
                printf("%g",a[x]);
                check = false; zero = false;
            }
            if (a[x-1] < 0 && x > 0){
                printf (" - ");a[x-1] = a[x-1] * -1.00;}
            else if (x > 0&& a[x-1] != 0)printf(" + ");
        }
        printf("\n");}
    }
```

Comment: I suggest removing all your casts from the `malloc(3)` and `realloc(3)` calls -- those can mask problems.

Comment: I'm also worried about the `if (p==null)` check in `polySetCoefficient()` -- that looks like trying to paper over a bug (and it returns _nothing_, even though the function isn't declared `void` -- oops). The `if(p)` guard in `polyDelete()` _also_ looks like trying to paper over a bug -- `free(3)` can handle `NULL` pointers.

Comment: Ok tried to change those, compiled, run and still same error. I have changed the add function, but it still produces the same error

Comment: Your title refers to "adding two pointers", which is misleading; you can't add two pointer operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug:

```
for (i = 0; i<=n;i++)
{
    if (p->coeff[i] == 0)continue;
    if (i == 0)eval += p->coeff[0];
    else
        eval += p->coeff[i]* pow (x,i);
}
```

Array indexes in C run from `0` to `n-1`; `i<=n` will evaluate `p->coeff[n]`, which is garbage data. (This is also garbage formatting -- I'd suggest running the entire program through `indent(1)`; the Linux kernel uses the `indent(1)` parameters: `-npro -kr -i8 -ts8 -sob -l80 -ss -ncs -cp1 -il0`; I like these.)

Here's the same bug, in slightly different form:

```
n = p->size;
double a[p->size];
for (x = p->size; x >= 0; x--)
{
    a[x] = p->coeff[x];
}
```

I expect `p->size` is the *size* of the array, not the largest array subscript.

Here's a different bug:

```
    if (a[x] != 0.0&& x > 1)
    {
```

You might be shocked how rarely `0.0` equals `0.0` in floating point arithmetic. Never do direct comparisons like this -- instead, check if the difference is near enough to zero for you to call it zero. (There's nothing about `0.0` here -- floating point comparisons across the board need to be handled carefully.)

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this it can be worth running your program through valgrind:

```
valgrind ./your_program
```

This will probably be able to pinpoint more or less exactly where any erroneous writes are occuring. Fix what you find, run through valgrind again and check that you've got them all. Note though that valgrind won't, at least last time I checked, warn you of out of bounds access to stack allocated arrays.

Valgrind is available as source [here](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html) but I'd recommend using your operating system's chosen method of package management to get hold of it, if at all possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link for downloading Valgrind?

Comment: Thanks, added a little more info to the end of the answer which addresses that.